Muuri floating elements
In muuri.js, elements are affected by gravity by default and cannot be moved to any available space. How to allow elements to take up any free space and be unaffected by 'gravity'?

Here’s an example of how it works in Gridstack.js; this is the
behaviour I want to achieve in muuri.js



Here’s how it works in muuri.js


